# Complexification of real irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I have been reading this set of notes: [http://www.math.columbia.edu/~rf/realreps.pdf](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Erf/realreps.pdf)

In section 4, theorem 4.1, there is a classification of the structure of $V$, the complexification of $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ based on the $G$-endomorphisms of $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ as follows:

Let $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ be an irreducible real representation and let $V$ be its complexification.
\begin{array}{h}
(\text{i}) & \text{Hom}^{G}(V_{\mathbb{R}}, V_{\mathbb{R}})\cong\mathbb{R}\iff V \text{ is irreducible.} \\
(\text{ii}) & \text{Hom}^{G}(V_{\mathbb{R}}, V_{\mathbb{R}})\cong\mathbb{C}\iff V\cong W\oplus W^{\ast}\text{ where $W$ and $W^{\ast}$ are irreducible and}\\&\text{ not isomorphic.} \\
(\text{iii}) & \text{Hom}^{G}(V_{\mathbb{R}}, V_{\mathbb{R}})\cong\mathbb{H}\iff V\cong W\oplus W,\text{ where $W$ is irreducible and $W\cong W^{\ast}$}.
\end{array}

The proof is omitted, so I am trying to prove it myself, but don't really know where to go with this. All that I have so far is that End$(V)\cong\text{End}(V_{\mathbb{R}})\otimes_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$, as I thought this would be useful.

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be an extra dollar sign in your point (iii).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sequence of exercises. The notation will be more uniform if we switch it to the following: I'll write $V$ for the real representation and $V_{\mathbb{C}} \triangleq V \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$ for its complexification.

1. Using Schur's lemma, prove that $\text{End}_G(V)$ is a finite-dimensional (associative) division algebra over $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Prove that the only finite-dimensional (associative) division algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ are $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{H}$. This is the [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)) and it's a bit tricky so you can skip this and just assume it is true for simplicity if you want.
3. Prove that $\text{End}_G(V_{\mathbb{C}}) \cong \text{End}_G(V)_{\mathbb{C}}$ (see how nice the notation is this way?), which you've already done. Compute the complexifications of $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{H}$.
4. Prove that in the direct sum decomposition of $V_{\mathbb{C}}$, if $W$ is an irreducible representation over $\mathbb{C}$ then the multiplicity of $W$ and of $W^{\ast}$ must be the same. (It's a bit misleading to work with the dual here; really we are working with the complex conjugate $\overline{W}$, which is the same representation but with scalar multiplication modified by a conjugate. It just happens that we always have $W^{\ast} \cong \overline{W}$.)
5. Write $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ as a direct sum of irreducible representations and compute $\text{End}_G(V_{\mathbb{C}})$ in terms of it. Now apply exercises 3 and 4; what do you conclude about the irreducible decomposition of $V_{\mathbb{C}}$?

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @philip: you're very welcome! If you'd like you could reply here with solutions, that could be helpful for people who search for this question in the future. (Feel free to skip exercise 2, that's probably covered elsewhere on math.SE anyway.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan do you have any hints on how to go about exercises 4 and 5?